# CSS animation progression between multiple animations

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I've been using Adobe Edge Animate to create what is basically an intro to a site. But I'd really like to try to code it myself by hand. And, to that effect, I have a question.

How would I string along multiple animations based on an array?

Here's what I'm thinking:
1. The array holds the name of each image.
2. I want to animation each image across the screen, one at a time.
3. Each image will animate once the one before it is done.

I know how to use the animationEnd event. My idea is that, basically, I'll append a child to a container div, assign it a class with the animation, use animationEnd to know when it's done, and at that time I'd want to go to the next image.

But how can I loop through each image when I need to wait for animationEnd to fire? Any ideas? Does anyone know of a good tutorial that touches on this issue?

I'd appreciate any guidance! I'm not asking for you to write me much code but just explain the way I can do the looping while waiting on animationEnd. I think that's where I'm stuck in my brain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use what's called a "recurring function", a function that calls itself multiple times. It usually functions a lot like a loop, but for asynchronous things (like `animationEnd` event), it's often the easiest way to go.

An example of usage in your case would be this:

```
var imgs=[/*images here*/];
function nextAnimation(curInd){
    var thisImg=imgs[curInd];
    //create the image element, trigger the animation, etc here
    //put the img element itself into a variable named imgElt, then:
    imgElt.addEventListener('animationEnd',function(){
        //only call the function again if this isn't the last item in the array
        if(curInd+1!=imgs.length)
            nextAnimation(curInd+1);
    },false);
}
nextAnimation(0);
```

Read it through a few times, you should understand it after a while. Also look up some other examples of recurring functions online, it's sometimes a tricky concept to master if you haven't done too much programming before

Comment: That's awesome! I'm not familiar with recurring functions. I see what your example is doing and it makes sense. And I'll read up on recurring functions to make sure I understand them as a whole.

Comment: I suppose when I want to end the recurrence, I set a flag or look at array.length to know when I'm done and need to jump to another function or do something else?

Comment: Thank you so much for giving me such an accurate and useful answer, all without berating me. Haha I appreciate it!

Comment: One last question: why do I need that "false" there?

Comment: you don't technically need it there, but you should have it there, I think it's required in older browsers. If you really care to know exactly what it does, look at the mdn article for `addEventListener`